# Is there a way to stop an event listener from iterating through all events if one event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, events

So I have a button defined like so...

```
<button id='myButton'>My Button</button>
```

My application needs to run smoothly on desktop & mobile devices, so when the button is clicked/tapped I need to run some code...

I do this like so...

```
$("#myButton").on('click tap', function()
{
    alert("Button has been clicked!");
});
```

My problem is that the event gets triggered multiple times when I use a mouse click. I'm assuming this is because the tap event is registering at each click. Ideally, I would just remove the click event, but I'm told that the tap event isn't fully supported for mouse clicks...

So in this case, I get notified twice via alert...

Is there anyway where I can make the listener not count the other event triggers if one is already triggered...?

Comment: Perhaps set a flag the first time, and reset it when you want to listen again?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the double event, on desktop & mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/Lqjp73rg/

Comment: That's odd @AmalAntony.... It doesn't seem to happen when using jsfiddle... But it does happen on my local version of the site...

Comment: @Ricky : Why does this question have an Android tag? There isn't anything specific to Android in what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can perhaps checkout [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to prevent any further handlers from executed

Comment: are you using rails with the gem fastclick (or maybe fastclick-rails)? i had issues with that gem a while back which caused a similar situation to only occur on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var $myButton = $("#myButton");

if (typeof $myButton.click == 'function')
{
    $myButton.on('click', function()
    {
      alert("Button has been clicked!");
    });
}

if (typeof $myButton.tap == 'function')
{
    $myButton.on('tap', function()
    {
      alert("Button has been tapped!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Well I assumed something like this would work, I just wanted to explore a less overcomplicated approach, if at all possible... By overcomplicated I just mean less code...